# How to send multiple products to Amazon Marketplace?

Tags: amazon-mws

I’m working on a stock control system and the client wishes to export their listings to their Amazon Marketplace account. So far, I've come across the SubmitFeed endpoint. However, all of the examples I look at only show an example of submitting a single product.

As Amazon’s documentation states you can only have so many active feeds at a time, I would have thought you would have been able to send multiple products in a single feed so you're not exhausting the feed limit, as I imagine power sellers will want to list dozens—maybe even hundreds—of products at a time.

I’m currently sending an XML documentation that contains one `<Message>` element, i.e.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Message>
    <MessageID>1</MessageID>
    <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
    <Product>
        <SKU>56789</SKU>
        <StandardProductID>
            <Type>ASIN</Type>
            <Value>B0EXAMPLEG</Value>
        </StandardProductID>
        <ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_NOTAX</ProductTaxCode>
        <DescriptionData>
            <Title>Example Product Title</Title>
            <Brand>Example Product Brand</Brand>
            <Description>This is an example product description.</Description>
            <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 1</BulletPoint>
            <BulletPoint>Example Bullet Point 2</BulletPoint>
            <MSRP currency="USD">25.19</MSRP>
            <Manufacturer>Example Product Manufacturer</Manufacturer>
            <ItemType>example-item-type</ItemType>
        </DescriptionData>
        <ProductData>
            <Health>
                <ProductType>
                    <HealthMisc>
                        <Ingredients>Example Ingredients</Ingredients>
                        <Directions>Example Directions</Directions>
                    </HealthMisc>
                </ProductType>
            </Health>
        </ProductData>
    </Product>
</Message>
```

The `<MessageID>` element suggests I’m able to specify multiple “messages” in a feed, but I’m not sure on the syntax as I would expect the `<Message>` to be inside a `<Messages>` element, in which I could specify multiple messages.

How can I specify additional messages and thus additional products? Or am I going down the wrong track?

Comment: @DanielWiddis Why have you changed all the apostrophes in my post to (typographically-incorrect) “straight” single quotes?

Comment: The answer to “why” is that I used a user script which made the change along with removing the Amazon tag and other formatting and I was unaware how important it was or whether the reason the script makes the change is intentional for accessibility. 

For my own education can you explain why it’s important? Is it better for accessibility?

Comment: @DanielWiddis It just seemed to be an odd thing to change. Like I say, it was the typographically-correct glyph for apostrophes. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Unicode

Comment: Yep, I wouldn't have done it manually. I was using the [Magic™ Editor](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#magic-editor) script and I just looked at the code and it's a dumb regex.  It only even did the "I'm" version and not other usages, so clearly wasn't intentional, just lazy.  I put it back how you had it.... thanks for letting me know, I'll look out for these types of autoedits in the future.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to send multiple `Message`s in one `AmazonEnvelope`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
         <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
         <MerchantIdentifier>MERCHANTID</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            ....
        </Product>
    </Message>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>2</MessageID>
        <OperationType>Update</OperationType>
        <Product>
            ....
        </Product>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

All messages in one feed need to be of the same `MessageType` (e.g you cannot mix Product messages with Inventory data) and have a `MessageID` unique to this feed.

Comment: Just in the nick of time. Thank you!